# adjusting floats to maintain high precision

Tags: python, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy, floating-point-precision

I am writing some Python code that requires a very high degree of precision. I started to use Numpy float64, but that didn't work as required, and I then started using the "Decimal" module, which then worked fine.

I would ideally prefer, however, to use floats rather than use the decimal module - and I recall someone once telling me that it's possible manipulate floats in some way so that the level of precision can be achieved (by multiplying or something?).

Is this true or am I misremembering? Sorry if this is a little vague.

Thank you!

Comment: Might this help: http://packages.python.org/bigfloat/?

Comment: I suppose you mean "staggered" floats meaning that the number is the sum of several floats ? There are algorithms which are dealing with this issue, but they are quite complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the kind of number you have. For example if you are adding values in the interval `[1...2)` you might be better of using offsettet values:

```
>>> a = 1.0000000000000000001
>>> a
1.0
>>> a+a
1.0
>>> a = 0.0000000000000000001
>>> a
1e-19
```

For simpler storage you can write them as tuple `(n, f)` with n being a natural number (int) and `f` the fraction in the interval `[0...1)`.

Computation with such kind of values is tricky however.

```
>>> (1+1, a+a)
(2, 2e-19)
```

If in doubt stick with `Decimal` or use [`bigfloat`](http://packages.python.org/bigfloat/) as suggested by BenDundee.

Answer (score 0):

Another useful package is [`mpmath`](http://mpmath.org/):

```
import mpmath as mp
p.dps = 64       #64 decimal places
msqrt(3)/2
mpf('0.8660254037844386467637231707529361834714026269051903140279034897246')
p.dps = 30       #30 decimal places
mpf('0.866025403784438646763723170752918')
```